# how do i create a function that calls next item on list and cycles through it?

Tags: python

I am having a hard creating a function that gives me next item on list and cycles through  it. I.e my list is range 20. With each call to my function i should get one item in that range and a subsequent call should give me next item + 1. Here is my start.

```
from itertools import cycle

def give_me_next(self, *args):
    my_list = range(20)
    saved = []
    # give me next item
```

Comment: Why not using `my_list.next()` ?

Comment: You might want to look into `generators`

Comment: @ForceBru -- `list` and `range` objects don't have a `next` method :-)

Comment: @mgilson, OK, `iter(list).next()`. Wouldn't it be OK then?

Comment: @ForceBru: No, because this would return the first element of the list every time you call it.

Comment: @SvenMarnach, @mgilson, sorry, I meant that: `a=[1,2,3,4,5]; b=iter(a); b.next(); b.next();` etc

Comment: Please show me  an example.  I am thinking i need to use pop() method and create a new list of items popped.Then keep track of them.

Comment: What is wrong with `x = cycle(my_list)` and then iterating over `x`, calling `x.next`, ...? You have the hard part already figured out, use `cycle`, you already import it!

Comment: @ForceBru -- Yes, that would work, but you're much better off using the builtin `next` function.  It handles the details of calling `.next` on python2.x and `.__next__` on python3.x

Answer (score 1):

If you've got a list with 'random' numbers you can use this:

```
list=[1,2,5,8,6,78,965,57,5]
b=iter(list)
try:
  while True:
    print b.next()
except:
  pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach, though it can be more elegant.

```
def give_me_next(lst):
    iterlst = iter(lst)
    return (iterlst.next(),lst[1:])

lst = range(20)
(x,lst) = give_me_next(lst)
print x # 0
(x,lst) = give_me_next(lst)
print x # 1
(x,lst) = give_me_next(lst)
print x # 2
```

Comment: I have to admit, this defeats the purpose of iteratble

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a generator?

```
def next_item(my_list):
   index = 0
   while True:
       yield my_list[index%len(my_list)]
       index +=1

x = next_item([1,2,3])

for _ in range(100):
    print next(x)
```